# How to make select box value selected

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have below html php form  with select drop down box, i have added 30 days using php with drop down,now i want selected value with from i have added jquery for show selected it is working but previous selected value not remove it display previous value please give me solution below my created form and also jquery for display selected onchange

```
<form name = "form1" id = "form1" action = "#" method = "post">
  <div id="myform">
  <select name = "DropDownList1" id = "DropDownList1">
<?php
$myVar="";
 for($i=1;$i<=30;$i++){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"  id="weeks"> <?php echo $i;?> <?php if($i==1){ echo "Day";} else{echo "Days";}?></option>
<?php }?>
  </select> <!-- finish the form in html -->
  </div>
  <select name = "DropDownList2" id = "DropDownList2">
<option value="1" <?php if ($myVar==1) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>First Week</options>
<option value="2" <?php if ($myVar==2) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Second Week</options>
<option value="3" <?php if ($myVar==3) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Third Week</options>
<option value="4" <?php if ($myVar==4) echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Fourth  Week</options>

</select>

  <input type="submit" value="go" name="go">
</form>





<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

            jQuery( "#myform #DropDownList1" ).change(function() {
                   var selbox= jQuery(this).val();
             jQuery("#DropDownList1 option[value='" + selbox + "']").attr("selected","selected");

            });

        });

</script>
```

Comment: why you are doing this? It would be automatically done

Comment: how to do this selected when we change value for drop down then option should be disply selected

 i have some static select box like

 <select name = "DropDownList2" id = "DropDownList2">
<option value="1" >First Week</options>
<option value="2">Second Week</options>
<option value="3">Third Week</options>
<option value="4">Fourth  Week</options>

</select>

so how to show selected for both select option please give me solution
if php or jquery have solution for this